Positioning a Dialog in Win32 C++
I am trying to create a dialog such that it always opens in the middle of my application window. This is the usual behaviour for a dialog created with something like MessageBox(). However, if the application window is moved before the dialog is opened, the dialog opens in the middle of where the window WAS and not where it is now. So something behind the scenes is obviously caching the position of the window.
Is there anyway to update that position to indicate where the window actually is?  The problem is that with MessageBox(), you don't get options of positioning a dialog, so I can't easily reposition it correctly.
There's an interesting answered question here:
How to Change MessageBox Position in C++ and I've tried the proposed solution and to be fair, using TaskDialogIndirect() almost works.  You can indeed set the (X, Y) position of the dialog, but the X position is slightly out and you can't alter the dialog size.
So I decided to create the dialog myself and thought that subclassing my main application window was the easiest.
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogWndProc(HWND wnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, [[maybe_unused]] DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"Okay", WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_VISIBLE, 50, 50, 100, 40, wnd, (HMENU)1002, GetModuleHandle(NULL), nullptr);
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            HWND owner = GetWindow(wnd, GW_OWNER);
            EnableWindow(owner, true);
            SetFocus(owner);
            DestroyWindow(wnd);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            RemoveWindowSubclass(wnd, DialogWndProc, uIdSubclass);
            break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(wnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

// hwd is the HANDLE of the main application window
void CustomDialog(HWND hwd, const std::wstring title, const std::wstring body, size_t xp, size_t yp, size_t xs, size_t ys)
{
    // Get the class name from the parent window
    std::vector<wchar_t> class_name(256);
    class_name.resize(static_cast<size_t>(GetClassName(hwd, class_name.data(), static_cast<int>(class_name.size()))));

    // Subclass the window and change WNDPROC
    BOOL t = SetWindowSubclass(hwd, DialogWndProc, 1, 0);

    // Create the modal dialog window
    HWND dlg = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME, class_name.c_str(), title.c_str(), WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_NOIDLEMSG, xp, yp, xs, ys, hwd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), nullptr);
    ShowWindow(dlg, SW_SHOW);
    EnableWindow(hwd, false);
}

The problem that I've found is that WM_CREATE is never received and I don't understand why. Surely, during the call to CreateWindowEx() the new WNDPROC will receive a WM_CREATE?
Or am I going to have Register an entirely new window class atom for this window?

Subclassing requires that the window has already been created. Obviously, you won't receive a WM_CREATE message in a window procedure you've attached to a window after it has been created. I don't know why you decided to use subclassing at all. You can call CreateDialog() and friends instead and all messages are delegated to the dialog procedure from the get-go.

@IInspectable Very true and if I'd got a Dialog template, then I wouldn't be asking the question. I even thought about programmatically building a template, but that's a lot of work as everything has to be word aligned.  Also, I don't mean to disagree with you, but I've found nothing that says a window needs to created before subclassing. You define a WNDPROC when you register a class without needing a window. How would you handle custom creation stuff if you subclassed after the window was created?  You obviously wouldn't get a WM_CREATE message if the window already existed.

If you don't want to create an in-memory dialog template you can script an empty dialog template in a resource script to use as a placeholder.

@TheWelder "I've found nothing that says a window needs to created before subclassing" - um, the fact that subclassing needs a target HWND isn't a giveaway? Your code is subclassing the main app window, not the dialog. "How would you handle custom creation stuff if you subclassed after the window was created?" - you should either create a dialog custom template, or register a custom window class, but if you don't want to do that then the only remaining option is to use a local thread hook to catch the creation.

@RemyLebeau But that's what I am trying to do. Subclass my main window, so as to then CreateWindowEx() a dialog without having to register a new class atom. The WNDPROC is a member of the WNDCLASSEX not the window, the window just uses the class.  The target HWND will just be used to find the window class in order to subclass it.  If you subclass an existing window before doing another CreateWindowEx(), I thought you would get the WM_CREATE messages. I didn't try your WinHook method to get the Create struct, which would probably work, it just seems a bit ikky.

@TheWelder Clearly you didn't read the documentation. Your understanding is incorrect. SetWindowSubclass() replaces the wndproc of a single existing HWND, it DOES NOT change the wndproc of new HWNDs of the subclassed window's class type. You might be thinking of SetClassLongPtr() instead.

@TheWelder In any case, subclassing your main window won't help you position the dialog where you want it. When you create the dialog, if it's not already positioning itself in the middle of your main window, then you'll just have to get the main window's current position first, then create the dialog and move it where you want. You don't need subclassing for that. But if doing that after the dialog is created is not the visual effect you want, then you'll have to hook the creation of the dialog itself.

"The WNDPROC is a member of the WNDCLASSEX not the window, the window just uses the class." - This misunderstanding is at the core of the issue. A window class serves as a template when constructing a window. During construction the defaults from the class are copied to per-window memory, accessible via GetWindowLongPtrW(). The window procedure is stored at index GWLP_WNDPROC. For the entire lifetime, the window will never get back to the window class again.

@IInspectable That is indeed my misunderstanding.  I use GetWindowLongPtr() for various things including changing the WNDPROC, but I mistakenly thought that this was happening against the WNDCLASSEX, which now I think about it... is a bit stupid of me to think that.

You are going about this all wrong.
For one thing, you are not subclassing the new dialog, you are subclassing your main window itself.  So you are only going to receive messages sent to your main window, not the dialog window.  And, you will never receive WM_CREATE in a subclass, as you can't subclass a window with SetWindowSubclass() before it has been created.  For that, you must register a custom window class, or else use SetWindowHookEx() or SetWinEventHook() to detect new HWND creations in the calling thread.
And second, you don't need a subclass/hook at all in this situation. You can simply calculate the desired position when you create the dialog, eg:
// hwd is the HANDLE of the main application window
void CustomDialog(HWND hwd, const std::wstring title, const std::wstring body, int width, int height)
{
    RECT r;
    GetWindowRect(hwd, &r);

    int x = r.left + ((r.right - r.left) / 2) - (width / 2);
    int y = r.top + ((r.bottom - r.top) / 2) - (height / 2);

    // Create the modal dialog window
    HWND dlg = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME, L"ClassName", title.c_str(), WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_NOIDLEMSG, x, y, width, height, hwd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), nullptr);
    ShowWindow(dlg, SW_SHOW);
    EnableWindow(hwd, false);
}

Or, you can move the dialog window after you create it and before you show it, eg:
// hwd is the HANDLE of the main application window
void CustomDialog(HWND hwd, const std::wstring title, const std::wstring body, int width, int height)
{
    // Create the modal dialog window
    HWND dlg = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME, L"ClassName", title.c_str(), WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_NOIDLEMSG, 0, 0, width, height, hwd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), nullptr);

    RECT mainRect;
    GetWindowRect(hwd, &mainRect);

    RECT dlgRect;
    GetWindowRect(dlg, &dlgRect);

    int x = mainRect.left + ((mainRect.right - mainRect.left) / 2) - ((dlgRect.right - dlgRect.left) / 2);
    int y = mainRect.top + ((mainRect.bottom - mainRect.top) / 2) - ((dlgRect.bottom - dlgRect.top) / 2);
    SetWindowPos(dlg, NULL, x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);

    ShowWindow(dlg, SW_SHOW);
    EnableWindow(hwd, false);
}


My misunderstanding is this:  I KNOW I'm subclassing my main window, but what I thought would happen was something like a new WNDCLASSEX, just with the WNDPROC changed to the new subclass proc. That's why I subclassed before creating the window.  I also know how to move my window, get the client rect of my main window to open the dialog in the correct place.  What I was struggling with was without a WM_CREATE, none of the buttons and things were appearing in the dialog. Obviously if you subclass after window creation, you won't get WM_CREATE anyway.
